# Turning off facial recognition in azure video indexer service classic account

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I wanted to turn off the facial recognition in the video indexer classic account. When checked in the Settings of the videoindexer portal I do see the option for unchecking the celebrity recognition but no option for complete facial detection off. How do we achieve this.

Comment: This seems to be about using a service, and not related to programming, such questions are [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [upload video API](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/api-details#api=Operations&operation=Upload-Video), you can use the excluded AI query parameter to specify the sensitive AIs you would like to exclude. (Face is one of them)

[image: Upload API]